# Review menu missing from top bar

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, top-bar

As of a few minutes ago, the review menu/button has disappeared from the top bar:

[image]

This seems to be a networkwide issue.

Comment: This is the result of some testing. Should be back and working to make sure it won't happen again.

Comment: @JonChan Not back for me on any site even after hard refreshing, even sites I haven't visited today. EDIT - it's back on MSO, but not here or SO.

Comment: @TylerH I think it's filtering out gradually... It's back for me but it took about 3-4 minutes after Jon posted that comment.

Comment: @Catija You mean filtering out to different sites gradually? Or users?

Comment: @TylerH check SO again?

Comment: @JonChan Just came back in the last 10 seconds, thanks. (Still missing from MSE here though. Actually, I dont think I have access to review queues here yet... nevermind)

Comment: @TylerH Users... I think they have different servers, so they may not all get the updates simultaneously.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was the result of some testing for topbar changes as we were turning on a new feature. This should be back for all network sites.

Comment: Will there be somewhere we can see/test the new version prior to it being pushed out to the network? Is there an estimated time-frame for when such changes will go live? Or is this just a very minor change, which doesn't alter the structure of the topbar (much)? I ask because I'd like to make sure that my [Top-navigation choices](https://stackapps.com/questions/7603/top-navigation-choices) script is compatible. (I need to finish up a new version anyway, so I'm also interested in when I'm going to need to schedule time to adapt to changes).

Comment: Testing how fast we notice the lack of certain things? Nice feature! ;-)

Comment: @Makyen this is a change limited to alpha users of [Channels](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352065/introducing-channels-qa-for-engineering-teams) that shouldn't affect the broader Q&A sites. If that changes, you'll be sure to know on Meta.